# How to add the geocode filtering to gxp.plugins.GoogleGeocoder

Tags: google-maps-api, boundless-suite, gxp

The Google geocode provides the capability of applying filters/restraints to the search, e.g. restricting the search to an area with a specific postal code, etc... I want to accomplish the same with the `gxp_googlegeocoder` plugin. Looking through the API I cannot seem to find how this can be implemented.

Has anyone else been able to accomplish filtering of sort on this plugin, if so what needs to be added/done?

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering) to the Google API.
Here is the [link](http://suite.opengeo.org/ee/docs/4.5/sdk-api/lib/plugins/GoogleGeocoder.html) to the GXP API.